# Check if Optional Package Exists

Tags: c#, uwp

I've created a UWP app and a UWP optional package.  I got that all set up using this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/optional-packages-with-executable-code

Everything is working as expected and I can use code in the optional package.  But obviously if I remove the optional package, my code won't work.  I don't want to have my app crash if the "optional" package isn't installed.

**What is the accepted way of checking if an optional package is installed?**  Do I just catch the exception?  That seems a bit hacky.

---

Example: When I reference `Class1` (in my optional package) it throws this exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Class not registered
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154)'

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the accepted way of checking if an optional package is installed?

You could use `PackageCatalog` class to get all the packages installed.

```
List<string> optionalPackageList = new List<string>(); 
foreach (var package in Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Dependencies) 
{ 
    if (package.IsOptional) 
    { 
        optionalPackageList.Add(package.Id.FamilyName); 
    } 
}
```

You could check if the `optionalPackageList` has contain the specified option package . For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.packagecatalog.removeoptionalpackagesasync).